# Highlighting specific words in content-editable element without changing the content-editable element

Tags: google-chrome-extension, contenteditable

We are looking to highlight specific words in a content editable but we don't want to replace the text in the content editable element itself. The reason for our request is because we don't want to interfere with the current content-editable element.

Our highlight is very minimal - just an underline.
So the way we thought about doing it is by getting the position of the words, and creating a div at the exact same position (on top of the current content-editable).

Are there any pre-made solutions that implement it?

Comment: Did you try mark.js? Otherwise this sounds like a standard thing to do using getBoundingClientRect.

Comment: @wOxxOm yeah, but mark.js replaces the content of the element with <mark>word</mark> which is problematic for us